# Go from my xampp server webpage to a filesystem file. I need to open the file localy not from apache

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink, xampp, href

I have an html webpage that is generated by a certain software. It has some functionalities.
I want to be a able to open this webpage from xampp where i have my index page. But whenever i link it via href, the link appears:  `localhost/mypage.html` . This disables the functionalities and the page cannot run properly.
What i need is to be able to open the file from xampp but in this manner :

`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/M-Docs/tobestored.html`

not `localhost/..`

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `file://` protocol specifically says, that you do not want to use a webserver. So either use XAMPP or `file://`.

Comment: What `DocumentRoot` is your Apache configured at?  If it is not `C:/xampp/htdocs/M-Docs/`, you can use `Alias` to map a URL to a directory.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500, Thank you for your reply. Can you please give me more details on what you are suggesting? I didn't quite understand what you meant.

Comment: If you want to access the file via a web server, which is Apache in XAMMP, you have to tell Apache where it is.  This is done by specifying where the documents are, using `DocumentRoot` directive.  Or, if you want to map `http://DOMAIN/something` to directory `c:/something`, you can use `Alias`.  This way you can view files outside the `DocumentRoot` directory.  For your `file:///`, Apache does not understand what to do with this.